# Anchor a label to the corner?

Tags: python, kivy

In Kivy:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        label = Label(text="TEST")
        return label

TestApp().run()
```

My label is centred in the window:

[image]

How can I instead anchor my label to the bottom right corner of the window?

You'd think

```
label.halign = 'right'
label.valign = 'bottom'
```

would do the trick, but as the [`Label` documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html) points out,

> The `valign` property will have no effect and `halign` will only have an effect if your text has newlines; a single line of text will appear to be centered even though `halign` is set to left (by default).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like adding the label to an AnchorLayout, then shrinking the size of the label relative to its parent widget, together achieves what I want.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        anchor_layout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='right', anchor_y='bottom')
        label = Label(text="TEST")
        label.size_hint = (0.1, 0.1)
        anchor_layout.add_widget(label)
        return anchor_layout

TestApp().run()
```

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the Label's text_size to its size, e.g. in kv `text_size: self.size`. The text_size controls the bounding box within which text is wrapped.

Comment: Is there an equivalent command that would work inside my example code, i.e. without the need to create a kv file?

Comment: For example, `label.text_size = label.size` does not fix the issue.